# Possible to sync a sqlServer view into a noSQL db like MongoDB or RavenDB?

Tags: mongodb, ravendb, document-database, nosql

I'm looking to get a complex sqlserver view into a documentDB like mongoDB for performance reasons. Is it possible to sync the two together? or What's the best approach to get each record/document from the view into the documentDB.

This is for straight up data viewing on the web only. no updates, deletes or inserts.

*wanting to learn about documentDBs, this would be a simple project for implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the source information is the relational database, you need some sort of an update process that happens when a row is updated.
You can do that either via your application, or using some sort of a trigger.
You get all of the required information from the database, and write that in optimized form inside RavenDB.
That is pretty much it, to tell you the truth.